# Removing quotes that seem to be nonexistent in MatLab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have an application that translates the .csv files I currently have into the correct format I need. But, the files I that I do have seem to have '"' double quotes around them, as seen in this image, which will not work with the program. As a result, I'm using this command to remove them:

```
for m = 1:currentsize(1)
      for n = 1:currentsize(2)
          replacement{m,n} = strrep(current{m,n}, '"', '');        
      end
end
```

I'm not entirely sure that this works though, as it spits this back at me as it runs:

```
Warning: Inputs must be character arrays or cell arrays of strings.
```

When I open the file in matlab, it seems to only have the single quotes around it, which is normal for any other file. However, when I open it in notepad++, it seems to have '"' double quotes around everything. Is there a way to remove these double quotes in any other way? My code doesn't seem to do anything as seen here:

[image: The variables as seen in MatLab]

After using xlswrite to write the replacement cell-array to a .csv file, one appears corrupted. Any idea why?
[image: Original on left, New on right]

So, my questions are:

Is there any way to remove the quotes in a more efficient manner or without rewriting to a csv?

and

What exactly is causing the corruption in the xlswrite function? The variable replacement seems perfectly normal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Please share your original data - the CSV file. (2) Please share the code you used to read in the CSV file.

Comment: the csv file is read with [~,~,text] = xlsread(filename)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "corrupted" file. That's not a corrupted file, that's an xls file (not xlsx). You could verify this opening the text file in a hex editor [to compare the signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). This happens when you chose no file extension or ask excel to write a file which can't be encoded into csv. I assume it's some character which causes the problems, try to isolate the critical line writing only parts of the cell.

Regarding your warning, not having the actual input I could only guess what's wrong. Again, I can only give some advices to debug the problem yourself. Run this code:

```
lastwarn('')
for m = 1:currentsize(1)
      for n = 1:currentsize(2)
          replacement{m,n} = strrep(current{m,n}, '"', '');
          if ~isempty(lastwarn)
              keyboard
              lastwarn('')
          end        
      end
end
```

This will launch the debugger when a warning is raised, allowing you to check the content of `current{m,n}`

Comment: the warning is raised every single cell so that would open quite a few instances of the debugger wouldn't it?

Comment: It will stop at the first and wait there until you press continue. I think this just happens for numeric imputs.

Comment: so I'm using an fprintf loop to write to a csv file and it seems to work. The one issue I'm having is that there is a '/A' every few lines. Is there any reason as to why this may occur? `fprintf(fid, '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d\n', current{n,:});` is what I'm currently using

Comment: @Ashwin: Tell us how to reproduce your issue and someone can probably tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I figured it out. There were 'N/A' in the %d column so I converted them to NaN first.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentionned in the documentation of [strrep](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) that :

> The strrep function does not find empty strings for replacement. That is, when origStr and oldSubstr both contain the empty string (''), strrep does not replace '' with the contents of newSubstr.

---

You can use this user function [substr](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25064-extract-substring/content/substr.m) like this :

```
for m = 1:currentsize(1)
      for n = 1:currentsize(2)
          replacement{m,n} = substr(current{m,n},  2, -1);     
      end
end
```

---

Please use xlswrite function like this :

```
[status,message] = xlswrite(___)
```

and check the `status` if it is zero, that means the function did not succeed and an error message is generated in `message` as string.

Comment: `'"'` is not an empty string. I think the warning is caused by the first input argument.

Comment: When I open the data in notepad++, there are double quotes surrounding every entry. When I open it in MatLab there are none. How do I rewrite the file as a .csv? xlswrite() writes the file with a different extension than the name is (which is why it's not reading in notepad). dlmwrite doesn't work as well (part of csvwrite) as the data I'm writing is a cell array. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe *notepad++* `simply add the `"` to show you that it is a string. This is just visually, they are not in the CSV-file. IF `xlswrite()` does not work what it is `message` returned, please ?